Append output file content in sql select query in where clause as a condition
I have a requirement where there is a select query and I have a spooled output.txt file. I want to use this output in select query to put in where clause condition as shown in below example. Can it be achieved using awk or sed or echo command to append that output content in this select query? Would appreciate if you help on this requirement.
cat output.txt
EQ7472993
EU2874748
Expected result.
select 'alter system kill session '''||sid||','||serial#||''' immediate;',program,trunc(last_call_et/60) last_call_et_minutes,module,
action,ecid,username,schemaname,client_identifier, process, machine, sql_id, status,blocking_session_status,event,state from v$session where ecid = 'EQ7472993';
select 'alter system kill session '''||sid||','||serial#||''' immediate;',program,trunc(last_call_et/60) last_call_et_minutes,module,
action,ecid,username,schemaname,client_identifier, process, machine, sql_id, status,blocking_session_status,event,state from v$session where ecid ='EU2874748';
I am trying to use awk and sed.
But awk inside awk command wont work, also query is complex with number of single quotes.

Why are you doing this in two stages at all - why not have one query that does all of this in one go? A simple approach would be to just change what you've shown to ... where ecld in (<the query you currently spool>) but you could probably rewrite it as a join.

I like MT0's answer, but if you really want to get sed to work, see e.g. How to escape single quote in sed? I think the most reliable way is to replace ' with hex code \x27 like so:
sed 's/\(.*\)/select \x27alter system kill session \x27\x27\x27||sid||\x27\x27,\x27\x27||serial#||\x27\x27\x27 immediate;\x27,program,trunc\(last_call_et\/60\) last_call_et_minutes,module, action,ecid,username,schemaname,client_identifier, process, machine, sql_id, status,blocking_session_status,event,state from v$session s where ecid=\x27\1\x27/g;' output.txt

You don't need awk since there's only 1 column in your output file.
Alternately, if you expect to frequently read your output.txt file into SQL queries, you might want to create an external table for it:
CREATE TABLE output_file
(
   ecid VARCHAR2(64)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    (TYPE oracle_loader
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY some_directory
     ACCESS PARAMETERS(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                       FIELDS
                           TERMINATED BY ','
                           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                           LDRTRIM
                           MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL)
     LOCATION('output.txt'))
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
    
select 'alter system kill session '''||sid||'',''||serial#||''' immediate;',program,trunc(last_call_et/60) last_call_et_minutes,module, action,ecid,username,schemaname,client_identifier, process, machine, sql_id, status,blocking_session_status,event,state 
from v$session s
join output_file o on o.ecid = s.ecid;

This assumes that output.txt is located in an Oracle directory named "some_directory"

As a frame challenge, why spool the output to a file and then try to read it back into an SQL query?
Use your query that generates the ecid values in another query by wrapping it in a sub-query-factoring (WITH) clause and JOINing it to the query:
WITH id_list (ecid) AS (
  <insert_your_complex_query_here>
)
SELECT q'[alter system kill session '||sid||','||serial#||' immediate;]',
       program,
       trunc(last_call_et/60) AS last_call_et_minutes,
       module,
       action,
       s.ecid,
       username,
       schemaname,
       client_identifier,
       process,
       machine,
       sql_id,
       status,
       blocking_session_status,
       event,
       state
from   v$session s
       INNER JOIN id_list i
       ON s.ecid = i.ecid;

If you then want to immediately execute your command, again, don't spool it out to a file but read it in a cursor in PL/SQL and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:
BEGIN
  FOR rw IN (
    WITH id_list (ecid) AS (
      SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT program,
           trunc(last_call_et/60) AS last_call_et_minutes,
           module,
           action,
           s.ecid,
           username,
           schemaname,
           client_identifier,
           process,
           machine,
           sql_id,
           status,
           blocking_session_status,
           event,
           state,
           sid,
           serial#
    from   v$session s
           INNER JOIN id_list i
           ON s.ecid = i.ecid
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rw.sid || ', ' || rw.serial#);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session :sid, :serial immediate'
      USING rw.sid, rw.serial#;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Note: Remove the ; terminator at the end of the ALTER SYSTEM statement because it is not part of the SQL statement and is invalid syntax when using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. You could also use bind variables rather than string concatenation (which helps prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities).
fiddle

Hi Team, thanks for your suggestion. Actually we dont want to execute it immediately. And issue is the ECID we are already filtering and storing in a notepad. Do we want to somehow use this notepad content output in our select query.
